# How to find out if this record was already seen by user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

On my site i wish to highlight news that were not already opened by the loggedin user. I just have no idea on how to make this without storing data to db(and this is a very bad option). Could you share please some information on how this is solved on modern forums, etc... Or your suggestions on how to make this the best way. Thank you for you advice!

Comment: Why is it a bad option? It's just a flag on the DB if they have read the entry or not.

Comment: Because there are about 100 entries a day and about 10000 users.... I do not think in modern forums there is a separate db table to hold such data.

Comment: Perhaps you could use cookies?

Comment: I thought abut it, but cookies seems to me not the best choice as soon as they do not live long or transfer between different machines...

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: DB Table**

You said you didn't want to do this, but really, it may be the most sensible option. You can store only records for users when they have read an article, to cut down on the number of records (assuming not every user reads every article). If all you need to store is `ArticleID`/`UserID` pairs, this table won't take up much space in your DB even when there are millions of rows.

**Option 2: Client-Side Storage**

Each time a user reads an article, store a record of it in their web client. There are numerous ways to do this, but I suggest you look into [persistence.js](http://persistencejs.org/). There are some downsides to this approach. It won't carry over from one machine to another, so articles that users read on there phone appear to be new when they see them on their PC. Also, you won't be able to access this information from the server to see which articles are most popular.